# Some tags are not trackable

Tags: bug, badges, badge-progress

For example, on ruSO Meta we have tag [выборы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B), but I can't track it and this badge isn't showed on [the badges page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf-says-reinstate-monica?tab=badges) in my profile.

On the main site we have tag [олимпиада](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0). Our member [reported](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10076/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?noredirect=1#comment42362_10076), that he cant track this badge.

[image]

But [he has posts with this tag](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%5D%20user%3A195342).

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get tag badges on tags that have [fewer than 100 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags) so it makes sense not to allow you to track them because it will only lead to disappointment when you don't get a badge.

> If enough votes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

The two tags mentioned in the question would seem to have 49 and 91 questions respectively at the time of writing this answer.